# standalone not working properly with PStricks?

Tags: pstricks, standalone, automata

I'm using Vaucanson-G to render automata (I also use TikZ, but here, I *want* Vaucanson-G).  Because it uses PStricks although I want to compile with pdflatex, I have put all my automata in separated files, which I `dvilatex|dvipdf|pdfcrop` before `\includegraphics`.  It works well, but I thought this was a typical example of use of `standalone` (standalone 2012/09/15 v1.1b).

However, the bounding-box is dead wrong.

On the following input:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{vaucanson-g}

\begin{document}
\VCDraw{%
  \begin{VCPicture}[-0.9]{(-1.4,-1.4cm)(5.4,1.4cm)}
    \State{(0,0)}{A}
    \State{(4,0)}{C}
    \Initial{A}\Final{C}
    \EdgeL{A}{C}{b}
    \LoopN[.5]{A}{a + b}
    \LoopN[.5]{C}{2a + 2b}
  \end{VCPicture}
}
\end{document}
```

it produces (missing labels on top, too much space below, overall it seems that the BBox is shifted downward)

[image: Vaucanson-G and standalone]

whereas `pdfcrop` produces the expected result:

[image: Vaucanson-G and pdfcrop]

Is there something I can do to get the expected result?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`standalone` uses the coordinates of the `pspicture` environment for the clipping.  Your y coordinate is too small. Use:

```
\begin{VCPicture}[-0.9]{(-1.4,-1.4cm)(5.4,2.8cm)}
```

Comment: Ah!  Ok, thanks a lot!  I wonder why the problem of the coordinates never shows when the Vaucanson-G picture is inline in a regular article (with text around it etc.).  Also, is there a means to have a tool report the proper coordinates?

Comment: no, there is no tool on TeX level. You can use `auto-pst-pdf` instead of `standalone`