# PSTricks with standalone class and newpage or pagebreak

Tags: pstricks, standalone, pdftricks

Can I use page breaks with the `standalone` class with `PSTricks`? Are there limitations? Or is there some mistake in my code?

I have been nearly successful in running the code below with PSTricks and LaTeX -> DVI -> PDF, but the `\pagebreak` command is ignored (no breaks, no errors) while the `newpage` command results in error.

Below is code from  the `PSTricks` examples page, with a different preamble.

**Update 1:** Both Adam and Herbert point out that passing `pstricks` to the `standalone` class resolves the issue of automatic page breaks between `pspictures`. Adam was first, by a whisker, so I'm accepting his answer. **Update 2:** I have removed all references to `PDFTricks` and `pdfpic` and asked a separate question, for clarity:  [PDFTricks with standalone class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160498/pdftricks-with-standalone-class)

The `PSTricks` code I use is from:  http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/bracket.tex

```
% !TeX document-id = {b32deebm-2e5e-41ab-43b1-c1c98454e234}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
% Author: Peter S. Simon, Camarillo, CA
\documentclass[landscape,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

% \nbox draws an ovalbox labeled by the argument which is also used
% as the node label.
\newcommand\nbox[2][white]{\rnode{#2}{\psframebox[fillcolor=#1,fillstyle=solid]{\makebox[3.5\unitlength][l]%
    {\scriptsize #2:}\rule[-.3\unitlength]{0cm}{0.6\unitlength}}}}

% \race[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
% \race draws two \nbox's vertically centered and separated by #4 (no units).
% #1 is the top \nbox argument, #2 is the race label, #3 is the bottom \nbox
% argument.
\newcommand\race[5][white]{\vbox{\hsize=3.5\unitlength\addtolength{\hsize}{2\fboxsep}%
    \addtolength{\hsize}{2\fboxrule}\nbox[#1]{#2}\par%
    \vspace{#5\unitlength}\par\nbox[#1]{#4}}%
  \ncline{-}{#2}{#4}\rput*(!
    \psGetNodeCenter{#2} \psGetNodeCenter{#4} #2.x #4.x add 2 div #2.y #4.y add 2 div     ){\small\sf Race #3}}

\begin{document}
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,framearc=0.3}

%  Winner's bracket
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,20)
    %\psset{unit=0.95cm}
    \rput[t]{0}(12.5,20){\huge\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \hphantom{The} Intratribal Winner's Bracket
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput[t]{0}(17,19){\large\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
        Tribe: & 
        \underbar{\hphantom{The Shoshone Tribe}} 
        \\[2\baselineskip]
        Race Time: & 
        \underbar{\hphantom{The Shoshone Tribe}} 
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput{0}(1,19){\race[yellow!40]{Car1}{1}{Car9}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,16.5){\race[blue!40]{Car5}{2}{Car13}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,14){\race[red!40]{Car3}{3}{Car11}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,11.5){\race[green!40]{Car7}{4}{Car15}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,9){\race[magenta!40]{Car16}{5}{Car8}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,6.5){\race[cyan!40]{Car12}{6}{Car4}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,4){\race[lime!40]{Car6}{7}{Car14}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,1.5){\race[black!20]{Car10}{8}{Car2}{.5}}
    %
    \rput{0}(5.5,17.75){\race[yellow!40]{W1}{9}{W2}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,12.75){\race[red!40]{W3}{10}{W4}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,7.75){\race[green!40]{W5}{11}{W6}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,2.75){\race[blue!40]{W7}{12}{W8}{1.7}}
    %
    \psset{angleB=180,linearc=5pt}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car1}{W1}    \ncdiag{-}{Car9}{W1}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car5}{W2}    \ncdiag{-}{Car13}{W2}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car3}{W3}    \ncdiag{-}{Car11}{W3}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car7}{W4}    \ncdiag{-}{Car15}{W4}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car16}{W5}    \ncdiag{-}{Car8}{W5}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car12}{W6}    \ncdiag{-}{Car4}{W6}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car6}{W7}    \ncdiag{-}{Car14}{W7}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car10}{W8}    \ncdiag{-}{Car2}{W8}
    %
    \rput{0}(10,15.25){\race[yellow!40]{W9}{17}{W10}{4.25}}
    \rput{0}(10,5.25){\race[red!40]{W11}{18}{W12}{4.25}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W1}{W9}    \ncdiag{-}{W2}{W9}
    \ncdiag{-}{W3}{W10}    \ncdiag{-}{W4}{W10}
    \ncdiag{-}{W5}{W11}    \ncdiag{-}{W6}{W11}
    \ncdiag{-}{W7}{W12}    \ncdiag{-}{W8}{W12}
    %
    \rput{0}(14.5,10.25){\race[yellow!40]{W17}{23}{W18}{9}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W9}{W17}    \ncdiag{-}{W10}{W17}
    \ncdiag{-}{W11}{W18}    \ncdiag{-}{W12}{W18}
    %
    \rput{0}(19,12){\race[yellow!40]{W23}{30}{W29}{2}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W17}{W23}    \ncdiag{-}{W18}{W23}
    %
    \rput[l]{0}(22,12){\nbox[green!40]{W30}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W23}{W30}    \ncdiag{-}{W29}{W30}
    %
    \rput{0}(19,5){\race[blue!40]{W23}{31 (if necessary)}{W29}{2}}
    \rput[l]{0}(22,5){\nbox[lime!40]{Champ}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W23}{Champ}    \ncdiag{-}{W29}{Champ}
  \end{pspicture}

\newpage
%  Loser's bracket
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,20)
    \rput[t]{0}(12.5,20){\huge\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \hphantom{The} Intratribal Loser's Bracket
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput[t]{0}(17,19){\large\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
        Tribe: & 
        \underbar{\hphantom{The Shoshone Tribe}} 
        \\[2\baselineskip]
        Race Time: & 
        \underbar{\hphantom{The Shoshone Tribe}} 
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput{0}(1,19){\race{L1}{13}{L2}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,14){\race{L3}{14}{L4}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,9){\race{L5}{15}{L6}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,4){\race{L7}{16}{L8}{.5}}
    %
    \rput{0}(5.5,17.75){\race{W13}{19}{L9}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,12.75){\race{W14}{20}{L10}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,7.75){\race{W15}{21}{L11}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,2.75){\race{W16}{22}{L12}{1.7}}
    %
    \psset{angleB=180,linearc=5pt}
    \ncdiag{-}{L1}{W13}    \ncdiag{-}{L2}{W13}
    \ncdiag{-}{L3}{W14}    \ncdiag{-}{L4}{W14}
    \ncdiag{-}{L5}{W15}    \ncdiag{-}{L6}{W15}
    \ncdiag{-}{L7}{W16}    \ncdiag{-}{L8}{W16}
    %
    \rput{0}(10,16.5){\race{W19}{24}{L17}{1.5}}
    \rput{0}(10,11.5){\race{W20}{25}{L18}{1.5}}
    \rput{0}(10,5.25){\race{W21}{26}{W22}{4.25}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W13}{W19}    \ncdiag{-}{L9}{W19}
    \ncdiag{-}{W14}{W20}    \ncdiag{-}{L10}{W20}
    \ncdiag{-}{W15}{W21}    \ncdiag{-}{L11}{W21}
    \ncdiag{-}{W16}{W22}    \ncdiag{-}{L12}{W22}
    %
    \rput{0}(14.5,14){\race{W24}{27}{W25}{4}}
    \rput{0}(14.5,7){\race{L23}{28}{W26}{2.5}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W19}{W24}    \ncdiag{-}{L17}{W24}
    \ncdiag{-}{W20}{W25}    \ncdiag{-}{L18}{W25}
    \ncdiag{-}{W21}{W26}    \ncdiag{-}{W22}{W26}
    %
    \rput{0}(19,10.5){\race{W27}{29}{W28}{5}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W24}{W27}    \ncdiag{-}{W25}{W27}
    \ncdiag{-}{L23}{W28}    \ncdiag{-}{W26}{W28}
    %
    \rput[l]{0}(22,12){\nbox{W29}}
    \ncdiag{-}{W27}{W29}    \ncdiag{-}{W28}{W29}
  \end{pspicture}

\pagebreak
%  Intertribal Competition.
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,20)
    % \psset{unit=0.95cm}
    \rput[t]{0}(12.5,20){\huge\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        Intertribal Competition
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput{0}(1,19){\race{Car1}{1}{Car9}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,16.5){\race{Car5}{2}{Car13}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,14){\race{Car3}{3}{Car11}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,11.5){\race{Car7}{4}{Car15}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,9){\race{Car16}{5}{Car8}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,6.5){\race{Car12}{6}{Car4}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,4){\race{Car6}{7}{Car14}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,1.5){\race{Car10}{8}{Car2}{.5}}
    %
    \rput{0}(5.5,17.75){\race{W1}{9}{W2}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,12.75){\race{W3}{10}{W4}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,7.75){\race{W5}{11}{W6}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,2.75){\race{W7}{12}{W8}{1.7}}
     %
    \psset{angleB=180,linearc=5pt}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car1}{W1}    \ncdiag{-}{Car9}{W1}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car5}{W2}    \ncdiag{-}{Car13}{W2}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car3}{W3}    \ncdiag{-}{Car11}{W3}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car7}{W4}    \ncdiag{-}{Car15}{W4}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car16}{W5}    \ncdiag{-}{Car8}{W5}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car12}{W6}    \ncdiag{-}{Car4}{W6}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car6}{W7}    \ncdiag{-}{Car14}{W7}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car10}{W8}    \ncdiag{-}{Car2}{W8}
    %
    \rput{0}(10,15.25){\race{W9}{13}{W10}{4.25}}
    \rput{0}(10,5.25){\race{W11}{14}{W12}{4.25}}
    \ncdiag{-}{W1}{W9}    \ncdiag{-}{W2}{W9}
    \ncdiag{-}{W3}{W10}    \ncdiag{-}{W4}{W10}
    \ncdiag{-}{W5}{W11}    \ncdiag{-}{W6}{W11}
    \ncdiag{-}{W7}{W12}    \ncdiag{-}{W8}{W12}
    %
    \rput{0}(14.5,10.25){\race{W13}{15}{W14}{9}}
    \ncdiag{-}{W9}{W13}    \ncdiag{-}{W10}{W13}
    \ncdiag{-}{W11}{W14}    \ncdiag{-}{W12}{W14}
    \ncdiag{-}{W13}{W15}    \ncdiag{-}{W14}{W15}
    %
    \rput[l]{0}(19,10.25){\nbox{W15}}
    \rput[b]{0}(20.7,10.7){\bf Champion}
    \ncdiag{-}{W13}{W15}    \ncdiag{-}{W14}{W15}
  \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This question `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134643/standalone-not-working-properly-with-pstricks?rq=1` is about something else altogether, despite similarity in the titles.

Comment: Naturally, I know that I could break the document into 3 parts and compile 3 times to obtain 3 pages, but I'd like to know if I can make a small amendment to the above and get 3 pages in one compilation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `standalone` class does not know which environment to put on single pages. Firt remove the `pdfpic` environment definition, you don't need it. You can tell the `standalone` package to put each `pspicture` environment on a separate page by either using the class option `pstricks` to the `standalone` class (`\documentclass[landscape,margin=3pt,pstricks]{standalone}`) which also loads the `pstricks` package so that `usepackage{pstricks}` is redondant, or you can use the command `\standaloneenv{pspicture}` to declare this environment as standalone (preferably after loading the `pstricks` packages).

N.B. : the boundaries of your `pspicture` environment are a little too small. The images are a little bit cropped. Use `\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(26,21)` for a better result.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this correctly places each `pspicture` on its own page, great! If I pass `pstricks` to the `standalone` class, can I still have a conditional to use `pdftricks` instead of `pstricks` if the document is compiled with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @PatrickT I don't know. I run my pstricks code in standalone documents with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` and then include the pdf pictures in the documents I run with pdflatex. The run with pdflatex is much faster because pictures are included instead of compiling pstricks code several times (mainly when there are several for generating refenreces), I can reuse the picture in other documents and I don't have to bother with the subtilities of `pdftricks` or `auto-pst-pdf`.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that's what I do too, but I'm going to introduce `LaTeX` and co to my students and want to show them all the possibilities in as simple a way as possible. I'll experiment further and ask a separate question if I can't get it to work.

Comment: thanks! I've accepted your answer since it solves my PSTricks question. I have edited out references to PDFTricks and asked a separate question about it, for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
\documentclass[landscape,margin=3pt,pstricks]{standalone}
```

and it will work. No need to delete the `pdfpic` environment.

Comment: Thanks Herbert, how different is this from what I already tried? And what do you mean by `it`? do you mean it should work with `LaTeX -> DVI -> PDF` and with `PDFLaTeX` ?

Comment: I forgot the `pstricks` option. I suggest to use `xelatex` then you do not need the `pdfpic` environment.

Comment: Thanks Herbert. The suggestion to pass `pstricks` to the `standalone` class is a good one. Adam had made the same suggestion earlier. Compiling with `pdflatex` and the `pdftricks` package does not work, however, with or without the `pdfpic` environment. Compiling with `xelatex` does not work either...