# PDFTricks with standalone class

Tags: pstricks, pdftricks

This is a `PDFTricks` question much more than a `PSTricks` question.

I am trying to use `PDFTricks` to compile a `PSTricks` document with the `standalone` class. I believe I have followed the manual's instructions, but must have missed something: I am compiling with `pdflatex`. I have allowed shell-escape as you can see from the first line of code in the preamble, and the log reports `\write18 enabled.` I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment psinputs undefined.
```

But I **do** have PDFTricks installed. As you can see from the code *below*, I pass `pdftricks` as an option to class `standalone`, now perhaps that's not allowed? Well, I also tried with an explicit `usepackage{pdftricks}` instead, and I get the following error (edited for clarity):

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
...                                               
l.82 \end{pdfpic}
```

The code works when compiled with `PSTricks` in a `LaTeX -> DVI -> PDF` workflow. See my earlier question [PSTricks with standalone class and newpage or pagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160383/pstricks-pdftricks-with-standalone-class-and-newpage-or-pagebreak)

The PSTricks code I use is from: http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/bracket.tex

```
% !TeX document-id = {b33ceedb-1e8e-41cf-91b1-c1c63954e674}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
% Author: Peter S. Simon, Camarillo, CA
\documentclass[margin=3pt,pdftricks]{standalone}
\begin{psinputs}
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  \usepackage{pst-node}
\end{psinputs}
    % \nbox draws an ovalbox labeled by the argument which is also used
% as the node label.
\newcommand\nbox[2][white]{\rnode{#2}{\psframebox[fillcolor=#1,fillstyle=solid]{\makebox[3.5\unitlength][l]%
    {\scriptsize #2:}\rule[-.3\unitlength]{0cm}{0.6\unitlength}}}}

% \race[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
% \race draws two \nbox's vertically centered and separated by #4 (no units).
% #1 is the top \nbox argument, #2 is the race label, #3 is the bottom \nbox
% argument.
\newcommand\race[5][white]{\vbox{\hsize=3.5\unitlength\addtolength{\hsize}{2\fboxsep}%
    \addtolength{\hsize}{2\fboxrule}\nbox[#1]{#2}\par%
    \vspace{#5\unitlength}\par\nbox[#1]{#4}}%
  \ncline{-}{#2}{#4}\rput*(!
    \psGetNodeCenter{#2} \psGetNodeCenter{#4} #2.x #4.x add 2 div #2.y #4.y add 2 div     ){\small\sf Race #3}}

\begin{document}

\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,framearc=0.3}
\begin{pdfpic}
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,20)
    %\psset{unit=0.95cm}
    \rput[t]{0}(12.5,20){\huge\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \hphantom{The} Intratribal Winner's Bracket
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput[t]{0}(17,19){\large\bf
      \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
        Tribe: & 
        \underbar{\hphantom{The Shoshone Tribe}} 
        \\[2\baselineskip]
        Race Time: & 
        \underbar{\hphantom{The Shoshone Tribe}} 
      \end{tabular}}
    \rput{0}(1,19){\race[yellow!40]{Car1}{1}{Car9}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,16.5){\race[blue!40]{Car5}{2}{Car13}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,14){\race[red!40]{Car3}{3}{Car11}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,11.5){\race[green!40]{Car7}{4}{Car15}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,9){\race[magenta!40]{Car16}{5}{Car8}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,6.5){\race[cyan!40]{Car12}{6}{Car4}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,4){\race[lime!40]{Car6}{7}{Car14}{.5}}
    \rput{0}(1,1.5){\race[black!20]{Car10}{8}{Car2}{.5}}
    %
    \rput{0}(5.5,17.75){\race[yellow!40]{W1}{9}{W2}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,12.75){\race[red!40]{W3}{10}{W4}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,7.75){\race[green!40]{W5}{11}{W6}{1.7}}
    \rput{0}(5.5,2.75){\race[blue!40]{W7}{12}{W8}{1.7}}
    %
    \psset{angleB=180,linearc=5pt}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car1}{W1}    \ncdiag{-}{Car9}{W1}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car5}{W2}    \ncdiag{-}{Car13}{W2}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car3}{W3}    \ncdiag{-}{Car11}{W3}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car7}{W4}    \ncdiag{-}{Car15}{W4}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car16}{W5}    \ncdiag{-}{Car8}{W5}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car12}{W6}    \ncdiag{-}{Car4}{W6}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car6}{W7}    \ncdiag{-}{Car14}{W7}
    \ncdiag{-}{Car10}{W8}    \ncdiag{-}{Car2}{W8}
    %
    \rput{0}(10,15.25){\race[yellow!40]{W9}{17}{W10}{4.25}}
    \rput{0}(10,5.25){\race[red!40]{W11}{18}{W12}{4.25}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W1}{W9}    \ncdiag{-}{W2}{W9}
    \ncdiag{-}{W3}{W10}    \ncdiag{-}{W4}{W10}
    \ncdiag{-}{W5}{W11}    \ncdiag{-}{W6}{W11}
    \ncdiag{-}{W7}{W12}    \ncdiag{-}{W8}{W12}
    %
    \rput{0}(14.5,10.25){\race[yellow!40]{W17}{23}{W18}{9}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W9}{W17}    \ncdiag{-}{W10}{W17}
    \ncdiag{-}{W11}{W18}    \ncdiag{-}{W12}{W18}
    %
    \rput{0}(19,12){\race[yellow!40]{W23}{30}{W29}{2}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W17}{W23}    \ncdiag{-}{W18}{W23}
    %
    \rput[l]{0}(22,12){\nbox[green!40]{W30}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W23}{W30}    \ncdiag{-}{W29}{W30}
    %
    \rput{0}(19,5){\race[blue!40]{W23}{31 (if necessary)}{W29}{2}}
    \rput[l]{0}(22,5){\nbox[lime!40]{Champ}}
    %
    \ncdiag{-}{W23}{Champ}    \ncdiag{-}{W29}{Champ}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{pdfpic}

\end{document}
```

An alternative preamble that doesn't work either is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pdftricks}
\begin{psinputs}
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  \usepackage{pst-node}
\end{psinputs}
```

**Something wrong with my preamble?**

Comment: Where is the sense to use `standalone` and `pdftricks`? _Both_ are used to create single pdf images.

Comment: The original code (see the url to `bracket.tex`) had this in the preamble: `\documentclass[landscape]{article}` 
`\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}` 
`\thispagestyle{empty}` 
and my purpose in using `standalone` was to remove these lines and obtain a nicely cropped image. My purpose in using `PDFTricks` was to obtain a `PDF` in one compilation instead of 3. I do not know much about `PDFTricks` and particularly as I have not been able to make it work, and may never have to. ;-) Thanks for your help Herbert.

Comment: Yes, that's ok. But you are using the standalone class to create a single pdf file. That is the reason why using the `pdflatex` call makes no real sense.

Comment: @Herbert, how do you suggest I compile the document? I tried `XeLaTeX` earlier with `shell-escape`, `pdftricks` and `pdfpic`, but that crashed. If I compile with `XeLaTeX` with `usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` it produces the correct output except that the `margin` is wider than the requested `3pt`, and it also generates errors. I compile with `pdflatex` only because I don't know any better. Thanks.

Comment: Also, `standalone` is a class and `pdftricks` is a package, is there a reason I should know why the two couldn't be used together? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A preamble that works with pdflatex, provided you have a relatively recent version, is without loading pdftricks and loading pstricks with the `pdf` option:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\newcommand\nbox[2]{…}
............
```

and removing the `pdfpic` environment. This gives:

[image]

Comment: Wow, could it be any simpler? Thanks!!!